# Cloud9-Problema ao executar código

Tags: c

O seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num = 123;
    printf("O valor de num = %d e o valor seguinte = %c", num, num+1);
}
```

Devolve no terminal do Cloud9 o seguinte resultado:

> O valor de num = 123 e o valor seguinte = |

Alguém me pode ajudar a perceber o que está a correr mal? Por que é que no terminal ele não assume a soma da variável?

O Browser utilizado é o Chrome Versão 34.0.1847.137 m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem um erro no seu printf. Deveria ser

```
printf("O valor de num = %d e o valor seguinte = %d",num,num+1);
```

Como tinha anteriormente, com %c, o printf iria apresentar o caracter ASCII correspondente ao valor dado. Neste caso, 124 corresponde à barra vertical |.

Edit:
Pode encontrar [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) os vários modificadores de formatação usados em C e o output correspondente.