# DevC++ retorna "arquivo fonte não compilado". Por que?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Eu consigo compilar o arquivo tranquilamente só que quando vou executar ele apresenta o arquivo fonte não compilado.Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    float a, b, c, y;
    printf("\nDigite os valores de a,b e c: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    while (a>b);
    if (b>c)
        y=(a+b*c);
    else
        y=(a+c*b);
    printf("o valor do Y e: ", y);
    while(a<b);
    if (a>c)
        y=(a+b*b);
    else
        y=(b+c*a);
    printf("o valor do Y e: ", y);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Qual é mensagem de erro?

Comment: arquivo fonte não compilado

Comment: Não é o problema da sua pergunta, mas isso aqui: `while (a>b);` é um loop infinito e vai travar o seu programa quando ele abrir.

Comment: Não relacionado com a pergunta, mas os seus printfs não funcionam, tem de acrescentar os modificadores de formatação (veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16027/8113)). Além disso falta-lhe um return 0 no fim.

Comment: obrigado, agora esta indo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev-C++ é um IDE obsoleto e por isso não recomendo a utilização do mesmo devido a vários bugs de projeto que ocorrem.

Caso realmente goste do Dev-C++ sugiro que instale o [wxDev-C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/) por ser um software que continua a ser desenvolvido ou o [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Quanto ao seu código tem várias coisas que devem ser destacadas:

Você não precisa nem de `#include <stdlib.h>` (embora usou a função system que está presente na mesma) vale destacar que não é uma boa prática chamar funções de sistema. E tudo o que usou o system foi para esperar após o encerramento do programa, para este tipo de caso, sugiro que utilize apenas um `scanf()`.

A biblioteca `#include <conio.h>` não é chamada em nenhum momento nesse código e também não recomendo que a use por questões de portabilidade. Geralmente vejo utilizarem a getch() da conio.h para a mesma finalidade que usou o SYSTEM("PAUSE") e ambas são desnecessárias principalmente porque o scanf da stdio.h consegue o mesmo efeito e você já está usando a mesma.

`while (a>b);` este while tem tudo para dar errado, você executa um loop sem, fazer nenhuma interação. Mesmo que um dos itens desse loop fosse o y (que você altera posteriormente) esse loop ainda seria infinito porque após a condição while você utiliza o `;`. Para colocar elementos dentro de um loop precisa-se de utilizar as chaves `{ }`.

`printf` não irá mostrar a variável a menos que especifique onde a mesma deverá ser mostrada na *string* de formatação.

Abaixo deixo um exemplo do acredito que procurava fazer com este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    float a, b, c, y;
    printf("\nDigite os valores de a,b e c: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    while (a>y){
        if (b>c)
            y=(a+b*c);
        else
            y=(a+c*b);
        printf("o valor do Y e: %f", y);
    }

    while(y<b){
        if (a>c)
            y=(a+b*b);
        else
            y=(b+c*a);
    }
    printf("o valor do Y e: %f", y);
    scanf("",&a);
    return 0; // return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```